# How can I disallow push to Mercurial repository published by shared disk method?

Tags: mercurial, active-directory, lan

We're using mercurial in my company's intranet and cannot publish for the time being through other methods but shared disk due to firewall restrictions. **I know this is not the ideal or the recommended method**, however, it will do for now (I'm setting up RhodeCode if I eventually get a server).

We found that we could really easily share our changes by just [sharing our repo folder](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/PublishingRepositories) through Windows using our Active Directory accounts (right click on folder, share with specific people), however I'd like to completely block out the possibility of having someone to push to a repository.

I'm 99% sure that HTTP is not being used, so traditional methods shouldn't work. **I'm looking even for a workaround as I don't think there is anyway to restrict this directly from Mercurial config**.

Comment: Have you considered simply using file-level access rights on the folders involved?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't work because what changes the files is the hg process in the remote machine. Read access will only block them from, say, deleting my .hg folder more modifying my source files

Answer (score 2):

As long as you're sure people are using `push` and `pull` to get the changes to from the shared directories (**Which is the only safe way!**) you can still use hooks in those repositories to block pushing.  Something like this in the repository's `.hg/hgrc` file will prevent pushing:

```
[hooks]
pretxnchangegroup.denyall = /bin/false
```

where `/bin/false` is whatever executable on windows always returns false/non-zero.

Also, consider making the shared repositories *bare* repositories by doing `hg update null` in them.  That removes all the files from the working dir so no one's tempted to edit in there.

Comment: Shouldn't prechangegroup be better to avoid transmitting data over the network?

Comment: Hrm, very possibly.  Whenever the existing AclExtension uses is probably the best choice.

Answer (score 0):

Everyone can share their repo (read-only) and ask other people – including the maintainer of the official repo – to pull from it.